# トグルボタンで、"マウスストーカー"とマウスポイントを追従，もしくは分離させるコードの書き方

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、トグルボタンで"マウスストーカー"とマウスポイントを追従，もしくは分離させようと試みた失敗作です。これを成功させるには、どのように書き換えればいいでしょうか。
うまく行っていたのですが、コードを誤って消してしまい、書き方を忘れてしまいました。
分かる方は、教えていただけないでしょうか。コードと、問題箇所は、下記の通りです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #00ff00;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

var CLOCK_HEIGHT = 55,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 55,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = -200,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 0;

var H = '✴✴✴',
    H = H.split('');
var M = '✴✴✴✴',
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・',
      S = S.split('');
var SPEED = 0.4,
    FACES ='✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴ ✴',
    FACES = FACES.split(' ');
var  HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
var  HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
var  HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.03;

var ymouse = 180,
    xmouse = 520;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
        xmouse = event.X + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
    }
  };
  document.onmousemove = null;
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearMonthDateDay = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getHours() < 12) {
    if (lastYearMonthDateDay != 'wa1')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", weekday: "long"  }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearMonthDateDay = 'wa1';
  } else {
    if (lastYearMonthDateDay != 'wa2')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", weekday: "long"  }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearMonthDateDay = 'wa2';
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = (lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = (lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = (lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = (lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

 var vis=true;
  function toggle(){
    vis=!vis;
    document.getElementById("tog").value=vis?"STALK":"breakOFF";
      if(vis){
            ymouse = 180,
            xmouse = 520;
          document.onousemove=Mouse;
    }
      else{
           document.onmousemove=null;
    }
}

initialize();
    </script>


  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:15%; width:100%; text-align:center;">
     <input id="tog" type="button" value="STALK" onclick="toggle();">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

問題箇所です。

```js
// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
        xmouse = event.X + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
    }
  };
  document.onmousemove = null;
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
```

そして、もう１箇所です。

```js
var vis=true;
  function toggle(){
    vis=!vis;
    document.getElementById("tog").value=vis?"STALK":"breakOFF";
      if(vis){
            ymouse = 180,
            xmouse = 520;
          document.onousemove=Mouse;
    }
      else{
           document.onmousemove=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: 上書きしてコードを消してまったときは、『以前のバージョンに復元』を利用すれば、解決できるかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何十回も同じようなことを書いていたのですが、やっとうまく行きました。
なぜ同じことを書いていたのに、うまく行かなかったのか、その原因が分かりません。
スクリプト内の"function Mouse(evnt){}"と"function follow(){}"が関連箇所です。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #00ff00;
}
    </style>

    </head>

<body>
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; bottom:8%; width:100%; text-align:center;">
 <input id="tog" type="button" value="BREAK" onclick="follow();">
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

var CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = -200,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 0;

var H = '...'.split('');
var M = '....'.split('');
var S = '.....'.split('');
var SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
var HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
var HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
var HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.03;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 180;
var currStep = 520;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
}
  document.onmousemove = Mouse;
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);

var flg=true;
function follow(){ 
   flg = !flg; 
document.getElementById("tog").value=flg?"BREAK":"FOLLOW";
document.onmousemove = flg?Mouse:null;
}
document.getElementById("tog").onclick=follow;
}


var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearMonthDateDay = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getHours() < 21) {
    if (lastYearMonthDateDay != 'wa1')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", weekday: "long"  }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearMonthDateDay = 'wa1';
  } else {
    if (lastYearMonthDateDay != 'wa2')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", weekday: "long"  }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearMonthDateDay = 'wa2';
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = (lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = (lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = (lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = (lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```